# Triggering Interrupts with Outputs, C

Tags: c, function, interrupt, msp430

I'm having a problem implementing and interrupt function in my already existing code.  Basically I want the interrupt to trigger either when a certain output is triggered or when the counter that triggers the output reaches the threshold.

Equipment:

Micro:  MSP430F5522

CCS:  5.5.0.00077

Compiler: TI v4.1.9

The device is supposed to scan for a light, and if the light is detected a certain amount of times in a row, an output is turned on that lights up a green LED.  If it fails a certain amount of times in a row, a red LED is supposed to turn on.

The problem with this code is that the red LED does not stay on long enough to show that there was a high amount of consecutive misses when scanning for the light.  The solution was to come up with an interrupt function that uses a different clock within the processor so the test cycle is not delayed and the red LED stays on long enough for the operator to know about the misses.

The RED/GREEN_LED_ON/OFF are bit wise output controllers defined earlier in the file.

This is the original function before I put the interrupt function within it:

```
#define PASSCOUNTERTHRESHOLD  40//20

   void display( char  event , char test )
    {
        int j,i;

        static int maxConsecPassingCount=0;
        static int consecPassingCount=0; 
        static int passingCount=0; 
        static int timeLimit=0;   // amount of time allowed for non detection before failure is asserted.
        static int consecFails=0;

        if ( event == DETECTED )
        {


            if ( stardata.outputOptions & DUALED )
            {

                if( ++consecPassingCount > 99  && !(EXT_INPUT)) // if no detection for long period , assume no motion and just reset counter
                {
                    RED_LED_OFF;
                    GREEN_LED_ON;
                    return;
                }

                if( timeLimit > 0  && !(EXT_INPUT))
                {
                    // evaluate whether the time limit has been violated by stopping timer and reading counter, reset counter for next time. if limit exceeded turn on red led
                    // else turn on green led
                    TA0CCR0 = 0;
                    i=TA0R;

                    if ( i  > timeLimit )
                    {
                        RED_LED_ON;
                        GREEN_LED_OFF;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GREEN_LED_ON;
                        RED_LED_OFF;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    RED_LED_OFF;
                    GREEN_LED_ON;
                    timer_us(50);
                    GREEN_LED_OFF;
                }

                consecFails=0;
            }


        }
        else if ( event==NOT_DETECTED)
        {
            passingCount+=consecPassingCount;
            if ( consecPassingCount > maxConsecPassingCount )   // find maximum string of consecutive passing tests out of a group <PASSCOUNTERTHRESHOLD> of tests to estimate the speed.
            {
                maxConsecPassingCount = consecPassingCount;
            }
            consecPassingCount=0;


            if ( passingCount > PASSCOUNTERTHRESHOLD)  // we should have enough data to predict the speed, so now calculate the maximum failing time allowed before we set the fail led.
            {
                passingCount=0;
                timeLimit= maxConsecPassingCount * stardata.starLimits[test].hiTestLimit2; //150;  // amount of time which is allowed between non detect intervals.
                maxConsecPassingCount=0;
            }
            if ( timeLimit > 0 && consecFails == 0 )                // start timer
            {
                TA0R=0;
                TA0CCR0 = 5000;
            }

            if ( consecFails > 100)
            {
                GREEN_LED_OFF;
                RED_LED_ON;
                return;
            }
                //consecFails=0;
            else ++consecFails;
        }


    }
```

I defined the timer used in the interrupt function in the main.c file as follows:

```
 TA2CCTL0=CCIE;

 TA2CTL=TASSEL_2+MC_3+ID__8; 

 TA2CCR0=125000;
```

This is the code with the interrupt function replacing RED_LED_ON output:

```
   void display( char  event , char test )

 {

 int j,i;

 static int maxConsecPassingCount=0;

 static int consecPassingCount=0; //kg 8/16

 static int passingCount=0; //kg 8/16

 static int timeLimit=0;   // amount of time allowed for non detection before failure is asserted.

 static int consecFails=0;

 if ( event == DETECTED )

 {

 if ( stardata.outputOptions & DUALED )

 {

 if( ++consecPassingCount > 99  && !(EXT_INPUT)) // if no detection for long period , assume no motion and just reset counter

 {

 RED_LED_OFF;

 GREEN_LED_ON;

 return;

 }

 if( timeLimit > 0  && !(EXT_INPUT))

 {

 // evaluate whether the time limit has been violated by stopping timer and reading counter, reset counter for next time. if limit exceeded turn on red led

 // else turn on green led

 TA0CCR0 = 0;

 i=TA0R;

 if ( i  > timeLimit )

 {

 #pragma vector=TIMER1_A1_VECTOR  //kg

 __interrupt void TIMER1_A1ISR (void)

 {

 RED_LED_ON;

 GREEN_LED_OFF;

 }

 }

 else

 {

 GREEN_LED_ON;

 RED_LED_OFF;

 }

 }

 else

 {

 RED_LED_OFF;

 GREEN_LED_ON;

 timer_us(50);

 GREEN_LED_OFF;

 }

 consecFails=0;

 }

 }

 else if ( event==NOT_DETECTED)

 {

 passingCount+=consecPassingCount;

 if ( consecPassingCount > maxConsecPassingCount )   // find maximum string of consecutive passing tests out of a group <PASSCOUNTERTHRESHOLD> of tests to estimate the speed.

 {

 maxConsecPassingCount = consecPassingCount;

 }

 consecPassingCount=0;

 if ( passingCount > PASSCOUNTERTHRESHOLD)  // we should have enough data to predict the speed, so now calculate the maximum failing time allowed before we set the fail led.

 {

 passingCount=0;

 timeLimit= maxConsecPassingCount * stardata.starLimits[test].hiTestLimit2; //150;  // amount of time which is allowed between non detect intervals.

 maxConsecPassingCount=0;

 }

 if ( timeLimit > 0 && consecFails == 0 ) // start timer

 {

 TA0R=0;

 TA0CCR0 = 5000;

 }

 if ( consecFails > 100)

 {

 #pragma vector=TIMER1_A1_VECTOR  //kg

 __interrupt void TIMER1_A1ISR (void)

 {

 RED_LED_ON;

 GREEN_LED_OFF;

 }

 }

 //consecFails=0;

 else ++consecFails;

 }

    }
```

I can't get the code to compile and I can't find a forum that discusses adding interrupts that are controlled in the same way I am using them.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?  Can I set a global flag when the red LED turns on to trigger the interrupt?

Comment: I guess you don't want to switch off the red LED, unless a certain time has elapsed since the last failure, or until the operator has acknowledged the fault.

Comment: I have never seen an interrupt routine placed inside an `if` statement. I'm sure @CL. could answer this, but I doubt that would even work. I believe at compile time the address of the interrupt routine is placed into the interrupt vector. I don't think it's something you can conditionally set.